# How to access constant variable in controller in nodejs

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have define a constant variable in model file and try to access this constant variable at the time of inserting data to table then it shows undefined. I am using sequlaize ORM and nodejs. I want to define three value for status like Active = 1, Inactive = 2, Deleted = 3, or is there any other solution to define this. I am using sequelize ORM 4+ version.

```
Model code is here

var Sequalize = require('sequelize');
var sequalize = require('../../config/db_config');

const ACTIVE = '1';
const INACTIVE = '2';
const DELETED = '3';

const User = sequalize.define('user',{
    user_id_pk : {
        type : Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull : false,
        primaryKey : true,
        autoIncrement : true
    },
    user_type : Sequelize.INTEGER,
    first_name : Sequelize.STRING,
    middle_name : Sequelize.STRING,
    last_name : Sequelize.STRING,
    password : Sequelize.STRING,
    email : Sequelize.STRING,
    mobile_no : Sequelize.STRING,
    is_email_verified : {
        type:Sequalize.INTEGER,
        defaultValue : 0
    },
    gender : Sequelize.STRING,
    profile_image: Sequelize.STRING,
    dob : Sequelize.DATE,
    is_active : Sequelize.STRING,
    created_date : Sequelize.DATE,
    created_by : Sequelize.INTEGER,
    updated_date : Sequelize.DATE,
    updated_by : Sequelize.INTEGER,
},{
    timestamps: false,
    paranoid: true,
    underscored: true,
    freezeTableName: true,
    tableName: 'user',
    createdAt:'created_date',
    updatedAt:'updated_date'
});

User.sync({force:false}).then(() => {
    console.log('Table is created!');    
}).catch(err => {
    console.log('An error occur when table is created!');
});
module.exports = User;

Controller code is here 

userController.saveUser = function(req,res){
    console.log(user.ACTIVE);return false;
    user.findOrCreate({
        where:{
            first_name: req.body.first_name,
            email: req.body.email,
            boltt_code: req.body.boltt_code
        },
        defaults:{
            first_name: req.body.fihhrst_name,
            middle_name : 'Rajeev',
            last_name : 'Varshney',
            email: req.body.email,
            boltt_code: req.body.boltt_code,
            is_active : '1',
        }
    })
    .spread( function(user, created) {
        var msg = '';
        if(created){
            msg = 'User inserted successfully!';
        }else{
            msg = 'User already exist!';
        }
        res.status(200).send({error : false,message : msg2, data : user });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log('Oops something wrong! ' + err);
    });
};
```

Comment: How is the question related to MySQL?

Comment: I'm sure you use it but I cannot see anything related to MySQL in the question. You should remove the MySQL tag and add the [tag:sequelize.js] tag. If you look closely, the name of the library is `Sequelize` and not "Sequalize" as you misspelled it. Then you wonder why the code doesn't work...

Comment: I mean, in the code. It is full of `Sequalize.INTEGER`. Even [Google knows](https://www.google.ro/search?q=Sequalize.INTEGER) it should be [`Sequelize.INTEGER`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use these variables in the same file, you just have to declare them and use it. 
If you want to access them from another file, you have to export the variables:

```
const ACTIVE = '1';
const INACTIVE = '2';
const DELETED = '3';
exports.ACTIVE = ACTIVE;
exports.INACTIVE = INACTIVE;
exports.DELETED = DELETED;
```

Now you can make the require of the file and access to the variables.

Answer (score 0):

In the **ModelCore.js** file export not only User, but also your constants:

```
// ModelCore.js
var Sequalize = require('sequelize');
var sequalize = require('../../config/db_config');

const ACTIVE = '1';
const INACTIVE = '2';
const DELETED = '3';

const User = sequalize.define('user', {...});

module.exports = {
    User,
    CODES: {
        ACTIVE,
        INACTIVE,
        DELETED
    }
}
```

And now import it inside of your **ControllerCode.js**:

```
// ControllerCode.js
const modelCore = require('./path/to/ModelCore');

const user = modelCore.User;
const {CODES} = modelCore;

//Using codes now should work
console.log(CODES.ACTIVE);
console.log(CODES.INACTIVE);
console.log(CODES.DELETED);

// Rest of your Controller code...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
We can initialize constant variable to model instance after creating the model instance. 

const ACTIVE = 1;
const INACTIVE = 2;
const DELETED = 3;

const user = sequelize.define('user',{..},{

});

User.ACTIVE = ACTIVE;
User.INACTIVE = INACTIVE;
User.DELETED = DELETED;

module.exports = User;
```